# Creating navigation out of specific IDs and their children?

Tags: menus, navigation, sub-menu, child-pages, wp-list-pages

I'm looking for a way to list three specific pages in a nav-menu (I want to get these pages by their unique page ID's), and also list the children of these three pages - appended to each list item, in a 'ul' of their own (So like a standard multi-tiered sub-nav type menu).

I've been trying to do this with `wp_list_pages()`, but `child_of` only takes one argument.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think there's couple of ways doing this.

1) [`register_nav_menu`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu), add your menu in *Appearance > Menus* to the registered menu location, then let [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) handle the markup for you

2) `register_nav_menu`, add menu in *Appearance > Menus*, then use [`wp_get_nav_menu_items`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/) to get the menu items and write the html markup yourself.

3) Have an `$array` of parent page ID's (*hardcoded or get them from an option/post_meta/wherever*), do `for/foreach/while` loop with the array and use [`get_children`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) inside it. You can either use to loop to simultaneously build the html markup or store the parent and child ID's to another `$array` and do the html loop later with it.